# Syntax guidelines for taking ownership and releasing objects in C++

Tags: c++, ownership

I want to know - are there any guidelines about syntax of C++ (non-)member functions, that allows me to understand (without comments, if possible) the ownership policy of its arguments and return value. By ownership I mean, that the owner is responsible for the destruction of the owned object.

I distinguish the following rules about arguments:

- take ownership
- don't take ownership
- share

and about return value:

- release ('return by value' is in this group)
- don't release
- share

For example, passing object by reference doesn't take it's ownership:

```
void func(object & obj) { ... }
```

Such guidelines may use standard constructions like unique_ptr, shared_ptr, etc. If there are no such guidelines, then the examples of possible syntax misunderstandings are welcome too.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know about `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and probably about `weak_ptr` too - the semantics of these are well documented and enable you to distinguish all the cases you mentioned.

Comment: Do you mean, given a function signature involving pointers, how can you tell who owns the memory and therefore who is responsible for allocation/cleanup?

Comment: @BjörnPollex "Such guidelines **may** use ..." - I mean, that if there is no another way to express the ownership rule in syntax, then such constructions may be used. For example, I don't know another simple way to share the ownership except as use shared_ptr. The more trivial syntax - the better guideline. Thanks for comment.

Comment: @flipchart: no, the questioner means, "how can I invent a style guide which, provided everyone follows it, allows them to tell who owns memory etc?".

Comment: @flipchart I mean: "is there a way to compose a function signature involving pointers so that the other developer can "tell who owns the memory and therefore who is responsible for allocation/cleanup". Steve Jessop is correct too - I mean the same thing.

Comment: I would say there is no need to invent one. Use the appropriate classes, and it will naturally work. Why rely on convention when the compiler can enforce it ?

Comment: @Matthieu: well, then the list of rules for which classes are appropriate, is the style guide. I guess the only non-obvious thing is that "don't take ownership" arguments *must not* use `shared_ptr`. Furthermore, there are two kinds of "don't take owneship", one that takes `weak_ptr` and one that takes a raw pointer or reference. This list doesn't distinguish those cases.

Comment: @SteveJessop: actually, `weak_ptr` *might* take ownership (since it can be turned, internally, in a `shared_ptr`. In a mixed codebase (either mixed with others working on it or in migration toward a clean model) I prefer to use a `pointer<T>` class to mark the non-ownership rather than a "bare" pointer which cannot distinguish the "it does not take ownership" from "it was written unknowingly"

Comment: @Matthieu: that's what I meant, holding the `weak_ptr` avoids assuming ownership, so in that sense it "doesn't take ownership". However, it does potentially affect the lifetime of the object. I suppose I could just as well have said there are two kinds of "sharing", one with `shared_ptr` and one with `weak_ptr`, my point is just that the question doesn't have a complete taxonomy. Using a `pointer<T>` class sounds to me like more than "no need to invent a style, just use the appropriate classes", it sounds like actual advice ;-) Would you revert `pointer<T>` to `T*` once migration was complete?

Comment: @SteveJessop: In a shared environment, probably, because it is self-documenting. For my own projects, I don't bother as much (`T*` does not assume ownership unless I am implementing yet another smart pointer).

Comment: @Matthieu: yes, I think it's fair to consider the `explicit` one-arg constructor of a smart pointer as a small but notable exception to the usual rules. Although you *could* pass in the parameter as a `unique_ptr`, and doing so might even make it easier to avoid a memory leak in the constructor itself.

Answer (score 9):

I can't see why using smart pointers doesn't suffice. I can't think of anything else that I wouldn't categorize as [code smell](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html). Using smart pointers over raw pointers makes ownership and responsebilities perfectly clear:

- `auto_ptr`/`unique_ptr` - single owner, ownership is transferred
- `shared_ptr` - multiple owners, ownership may be transferred
- `scoped_ptr` - single owner, ownership cannot be transferred
- `weak_ptr` - observer (but `shared_ptr` may be created from `weak_ptr`)

I think that these suffice to clearly show the responsibilities, e.g.

```
void func(std::auto_ptr<Class> input) {...} // func() takes ownership of input
void func(std::shared_ptr<Class> input) {...} // func() and caller share ownership
std::auto_ptr<Class> func() {...} // caller takes ownership of returned value
std::shared_ptr<Class> func() {...} // func() and caller shares ownership of returned object
std::weak_ptr<Class> func() {...} // func() owns created object, but caller may observe it
```

As you mention, references are also great in this sense. Note if there's a need to free the pointers using some custom mechanism, `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` supports custom deleters. `auto_ptr` does not have this capability.

Note! If you are using C++ pre-11, you'll have to resort to `boost::shared_ptr` and `boost:weak_ptr`.

Comment: *What possibilities are you missing?* The common case is when writing the boilerplate abstraction layer for anything that does not go through `new`, `new[]`, `delete`, `delete[]`, but has its own allocator or reference counting scheme -- commonly when incorporating external APIs with your codebase.

Comment: @Justin: If it has its own allocator, then `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` can be given custom deleters to deal with that. If it has its own reference counting scheme, then `boost::intrusive_ptr` is a good choice - it handles the smart-pointer semantics, and you only have to take care of the reference counting itself.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I've updated the answer with a remark about custom deleters, thx.

Comment: @Mike Seymour +1 all valid points. however, I still don't see 100% coverage using these utilities, and the OP's question is still valid because these types are not always sufficient. some more examples: 1) in the case of the special allocator, the object may need to to reference its allocator (or some other context). 2) abstraction and exporting of implementations to reduce compile times 3) boost or more modern standard features aren't an option for everybody 4) some resources are best served by further specializations/features these types do not offer.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated and should not be used for anything. The uses in this answer can be replaced by `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

I just use this syntax for parameters where needed:

example constructor declaration:

```
t_array(const t_ownership_policy::t_take& policy, THESpecialType* const arg);
```

In use at the callsite:

```
t_array array(t_ownership_policy::Take, THESpecialTypeCreate(...));
```

Where `t_ownership_policy::t_take` is just a dummy overload disambiguator typename.

In this system, there are multiple policies, each with separate types. I favored unique types per policy because a typed enumeration (for example) does not support initialization as easily, and it's too easy to pass an unsupported policy to a function or constructor. 'Polymorphic' policies can reduce symbol count, but it's a pain because it pushes error detection to runtime.

For 'returning':

```
void func(t_container<t_type>& outValue);
```

Where `t_container` is whichever pointer container type you choose. Then the container type already implements the necessary boilerplate. This container may be something like a `shared_ptr`, or some specialization you have written.

and for more elaborate types, i'll often use syntax like so:

```
void func(t_special_container& outValue) {
  ...
  outValue.take(ptr);
  - or -
  outValue.copy(ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, then Boost [call_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) might be what you are looking for:

The example (copied from the docs goes):

```
template <class T>
struct contained
{
   // define our typedefs first, arrays are stored by value
   // so value_type is not the same as result_type:
   typedef typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type       param_type;
   typedef typename boost::call_traits<T>::reference        reference;
   typedef typename boost::call_traits<T>::const_reference  const_reference;
   typedef T                                                value_type;
   typedef typename boost::call_traits<T>::value_type       result_type;

   // stored value:
   value_type v_;

   // constructors:
   contained() {}
   contained(param_type p) : v_(p){}
   // return byval:
   result_type value() { return v_; }
   // return by_ref:
   reference get() { return v_; }
   const_reference const_get()const { return v_; }
   // pass value:
   void call(param_type p){}

};
```

Not much clearer than `param_type`, `reference_type` and `return_type` to indicate what is meant.