# About ownership of heap objects and C++ & pass-by-reference parameters

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, pass-by-reference, bada, ownership

I would like my class to be:

```
class NumberedString : public Object {
public:
    String newName;
    short nameID;
    NumberedString(String &newName, short nameID) : newName(newName), nameID(nameID) {}
};

HashMap uniqueStrs;//For later.
```

An instantiation of this will be passed to a `HashMap` which takes over ownership of its the heap allocation:

*In HashMap.h (say):*

```
virtual result Add(const Object& key, const Object& value);
```

Now this is where I get confused. I was allocating the `String` in the line that called `Add`:

```
uniqueStrs.Add(*(new String(L"XYX_say")), *pNewLoc);
```

The `HashMap` would then free this memory for me despite only accepting a reference to it. Maybe I lost a decade to `C` over the new millenium but I thought this was impossible?

If it's not then I should be able to write something like:

```
~NumberedString() {
    delete &newName;
}
```

for my class, but I'd never have guessed unless I saw this library [`HashMap::RemoveAll()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20140114192217/http://developer.bada.com/help/topic/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Base_1_1Collection_1_1HashMap.html#ad800eeb9c3a6a8d80567bf77fce70b08) doing the equivalent. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992600/syntax-guidelines-for-taking-ownership-and-releasing-objects-in-c) states that this is impossible but falls back to reliance on `auto_ptr` and `shared_ptr` but my "platform supports only STL(Standard Template Library (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/))." (out of the entire "Standard C++ Library"). Could all answers please refrain from such references.

Thank you.

**LINKS prompted by comments**

I can't post the links as comments so please see the `Add` method and an example of its suggested use: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140114192217/http://developer.bada.com/help/topic/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Base_1_1Collection_1_1HashMap.html#af287eb7c42a186e089bbb74d0c05227f) And Benj, [String](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Base_1_1String.html) is not std::string no, sorry.

**ALSO**

I know it can cause crashes trying to delete stack objects but I don't get how `HashMap` can claim to be able to delete heap objects. I have coded up the above class to try and recreate this behaviour but I cannot accomplish the feat, hence the question.

**In response to "Useless"**

@Useless: Mightn't it be possible to pass to `foo(int &bar)` the variable `*pBar`, declared `int pBar = new int(1);` and then `foo` assumes ownership with

```
foo(int &bar) {
    int *__pBar = &bar;
    delete __pBar;
}
```

? I was going to try, but I am beginning to be cautious not to believe too much of what the documentation says. Though it was generated from the header which is saying

```
class _EXPORT_BASE_ HashMap :
    public IMap,
    public Object
    {
    virtual result Add(const Object& key, const Object& value);
        //other stuff
    };
```

Comment: So what is your question? Does your code compile at all? `Add()` argument doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @BojanKomazec: I just linked to the class that has `Add(const Object &key...)` and still claims to be able to delete them for you! http://developer.bada.com/help/topic/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Base_1_1Collection_1_1HashMap.html#ad800eeb9c3a6a8d80567bf77fce70b08

Comment: Is "String" actually std::string ?

Comment: What is your question? can you present some compilable code that illustrates your problem? and what does passing a reference have to do with not being able to delete memory?

Comment: `uniqueStrs.Add(*(new String(L"XYX_say"), *pNewLoc))` is almost certainly not doing what you want, that immediately deferences the pointer and leaks the memory...  You're passing into the hash map by value.

Comment: @John I am not familiar with Bada SDK but usually when you add an object to a collection, its copy is actually made and stored in collection. Those two objects then have independent lifetimes. Having a proper copy constructors is essential here.

Comment: @BojanKomazec this is not the case here, please see linked classes.

Comment: @Benj I goofed the bracketing of that string, my copy paste was obviously not "XYX_say" but sourced from another call sorry all.

Comment: Re. the last (`foo/bar`) edit: you totally _can_ do that, and in fact it is. I'm just saying they've chosen a stupidly misleading way to express the transfer of ownership, because you _usually_ use pointers for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's certainly nothing syntactically wrong with it.  The only
syntax rule for delete is that its operand has to be a pointer.
Semantically: the pointer must be value returned from `new`, and that's
where this idiom stinks; if I see a function taking a const reference,
I'm normally justified in supposing that I can pass it a local variable,
or a temporary, or such.  In which case, the `delete` is going to cause
really big problems.

More generally, having looked at the library documentation: I would
avoid this library like the plague.  It reminds me of a library from the
NHS, which was widespread in the early days of C++: it requires that
everything derive from `Object`, and containers contain `Object*`.
Experience with this library back then (late 1980's) led to the
conclusion that it didn't work, and were part of the motivation for
adding templates to the language, so that we could write things that did
work.  Using this library is basically going back 25 years in time, and
throwing out everything we've learned since then.  (Java followed a
similar route about 10 years later, so it's not something specific to
C++.  Basically, the solution proposed is one that was developed for
languages with full dynamic type checking, like Lisp, Smalltalk or more
recently Python, and doesn't work in languages with static type
checking, like C++ or Java.)

Comment: I've ammended my question to describe how I think I could emulate this library's _atrocious_ behaviour. I've taken everyone's advice on board and gone with Bojan's `String *pNewName;` implementation but I am still curious about how the library's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> uniqueStrs.Add(*new String(L"XYX_say"), *pNewLoc);
> ```

<sub>Removed the extra parentheses, which were wrong; I guess you didn't want to ask about them.</sub>

> The HashMap would then free this memory for me despite only accepting a reference to it. Maybe I lost a decade to C over the new millenium but I thought this was impossible?

It is possible, and `delete &newName;` is legal, *given that* `newName` is actually a result of  `*new ...`. However, it is unidiomatic especially with the decaration

```
virtual result Add(const Object& key, const Object& value);
```

Since it takes its arguments as const-references, it can also take rvalues implicitly converted to const references:

```
uniqueStrs.Add(String(L"XYX_say"), something)
```

This will lead to crashes (because the rvalue ceases to exist after the call, because the `delete` will delete a non-heap allocated object etc.) but the interface doesn't clearly show it and it is customary to pass rvalues to functions taking const-references.

Comment: I see I typoed that Add call. Please see updated (but still very bracketed) question.

Comment: I know it can cause crashes trying to delete stack objects but I don't get how it can claim to be able to delete heap objects. I have coded up the above class to try and recreate this behavious but I cannot accomplish the feat, hence the question.

Comment: There's no magic. Just `int& x = *new int; delete &x;` will work. If you're having specific problems, you should post the specific code.

Comment: Your answer/comment doesn't describe how I can delete a parameter that was first allocated and then passed by reference to a new owner.

Comment: @John: It's nothing new in C++. It's just unusual.

Comment: That bada code is _atrocious_. It looks like Samsung translated it badly from Java. @John, you just have to accept that the API is _really_ taking a pointer and transferring ownership to the container, using stupidly misleading syntax.

Comment: @Useless: Mightn't it be possible to pass to `foo(int &bar)` the variable `*pBar`, declared `int pBar = new int(1);` and then `foo` assumes ownership with `foo(int &bar) {int *__pBar = &bar;}`? I was going to try, but I am beginning to be cautious not to believe too much of what the documentation says, although it was generated from the header which has `virtual result Add(const Object& key, const Object& value);` This hasn't formatted so I will append it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
class NumberedString : public Object {
    String newName;
    ...
};
```

compiler generates `NumberedString`'s destructor which automatically calls destructors of all member objects, including `newName`. Therefore you don't need to do something like this (which doesn't make sense anyway):

```
~NumberedString() {
    delete &newName;
}
```

I had a look at Bada API which for `HashMap::Add(const Object& key, const Object& value)`
says:

> This method performs a shallow copy. It adds only the pointer; not the
>   element itself.

This interface is a bit misleading and potentially dangerous - jpalacek explained what can happen if you pass object which is not on the heap. In my opinion, this function should have pointer types as arguments, that would be much clearer.

For `HashMap::Remove(const Object& key, bool deallocate = false)` and `HashMap::RemoveAll(bool deallocate = false)` documentation says:

> Removes all the object pointers in the collection.  If the deallocate
>   param is true, it also removes all of the objects.

So, by default these functions will just remove pointers but your objects will still be alive.

In your current implementation `NumberedString` is responsible for the lifetime of its members. When instance of that class is destroyed, its members will be destroyed. If you pass its members to `HashMap`, delete your object/remove it from the stack and then call `HashMap::RemoveAll(false)`, `HashMap` won't try do deallocate objects twice. Be aware that after deleting your object `HashMap` will be holding pointers to deallocated memory (*dangling pointers*) which is dangerous. If you call `HashMap::RemoveAll(true)`, `HashMap` will try to deallocate memory that has already been deallocated, which is dangerous as well.

Better design could be to have something like this:

```
class NumberedString : public Object {
    String* pNewName;
    short* pNameID;
    ...
}
```

where you make sure that `NumberedString` doesn't own `String` and `short` objects (doesn't delete them in its destructor). This class would be keeping pointers, just as `HashMap`. You will need to define who's creating and who's destroying these objects. E.g. you could create them, pass their addresses to `NumberedString` and `HashMap` and then delegate `HashMap` to delete them by calling `HashMap::RemoveAll(true)`. Or, you can delete them yourself and then call `HashMap::RemoveAll(false)`.

The conclusion is: be very careful with this silly API and pay attention to when and by whom are your objects created and deleted.